# How to "install" (copy) header files of transitively linked libraries with CMake

Tags: build, cmake, header-files

I have 3 libraries: *A*, *B*, *C*.

C links against B. B links against A (C will "link" against B as well).

```
target_link_libraries(B A)
target_link_libraries(C B)
```

Each of these libraries has been set with a PUBLIC_HEADER property, which contains the path of the respective header files. For instance:

```
set_target_properties(A PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "A.h")
set_target_properties(B PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "B.h")
set_target_properties(C PROPERTIES PUBLIC_HEADER "C.h")
```

When I compile and install the library *C* in the "build" directory (with *make && make install*), I want both the output library file and **all** the "linked" header files to be there.

To this aim, I used the following directive:

```
install(TARGETS C
        RUNTIME DESTINATION       build
        LIBRARY DESTINATION       build
        ARCHIVE DESTINATION       build
        PUBLIC_HEADER DESTINATION build)
```

However, only *C.h* file (and the library) gets copied into the *build* directory.

How can library *C* inherit the PUBLIC_HEADER(s) of the *A/B* linked libraries?

Comment: `A.h` is the *PUBLIC_HEADER* for `A` library. So it is installed with `A` target. Otherwise, without installing `A`, I see no needs in installing `A.h`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev I understand why it works that way. I am asking if there is a way to "inherit" the PUBLIC_HEADER(s) of the linked libraries (something similar to *target_include_directories*)

Comment: I know no way for *automatically* propagate PUBLIC_HEADER property from the original target to the target it is linked into. Could you describe, **why** do you need PUBLIC_HEADER of the target being installed without installing that target? Looks like XY problem for me..